# After set up Appium will pop not find out aapt

Tags: appium

I'm trying set up me Appium Automatic Server ,after setup done tap start session botten will show bellow error messages.

An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. 
   Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in PATH. Please set the 
   ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory 
   path.

after I follow change , but doesn't work

```
export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk 
export JAVA_HOHE="$（/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)" 
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/hauying/Library/Andriod/sdk 
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH 
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH 
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/29.0.1:$PATH 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin 
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platfrom-tools 
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with your android setup. Do you have "\tools\bin\" with adb.exe and other files in your android sdk folder? This would be the same folder which contains `platform-tools`, `build-tools` etc. Is adb being recognized when you try to execute adb devices from terminal or command line?

Comment: ＠  PRERNA PAL yes I can use " adb devices " It working

Comment: i follow i create new folder I saw my folder is /home/hauying/Android/tool  i setup be /home/hauying/Library/Android/sdk/   is working but pop another error messages :  
 An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find 'aapt' in PATH. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.

Comment: I restart my latop it will pop error again..... and didn't work

Comment: my latop is Linux the PATH how to edit

Comment: I use this sudo nano ~/bash_profile

Comment: export JAVA_HOHE="$（/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"

export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/hauying/Library/Andriod/sdk/emulator
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/hauying/Library/Andriod/sdk/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/hauying/Library/Andriod/sdk/tools/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/hauying/Library/Andriod/sdk/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools

Comment: anything i need to change?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `bash_profile` to access adb from the terminal 
on PC open terminal, 
A good way to edit the file is to use nano or vi. You can use the command sudo nano ~/.bash_profile, and enter your admin password when prompted, then add the below line to the end and save the file. Make sure you chnage according to your file path on your machine

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/krishnachetan/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/28.0.3:$PATH
```

To activate the changes in the current shell, you have to "source" the updated bash_profile file. You do this with the command:

$ source ~/.bash_profile
This simply imports the file's settings into the current shell. Now every time you open your shell, your bash_profile will automatically be "sourced" and you won't need to run this command every time.

Comment: aapt is part of  build tools, so make sure you chnage version number of builds tools according to your path

Comment: I need delete my old export?

Comment: add export for build tools as well